# Convert column with hex value into multiple columns with binary value

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with a column containing hexadecimal data; which I would like to covert into binary and create new columns with the binary data. Example code,

```
library(data.table)
library(BMS)

# Create a data table
dt <- data.table(Z=c(1:4), 
                 HDATA=c("1234","5678","9ACB","DEF0"))
# Convert the HDATA column to binary
Bin_names <- sapply(c(15:0), function(x) paste0('C',x))
dt[,Bin_names:=hex2bin(as.character(HDATA)),]
```

However this gives me the following error message,

Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(Bin_names, hex2bin(as.character(HDATA))),  :
  Supplied 76 items to be assigned to 4 items of column 'Bin_names' (72 unused)

and the modified data table looks like this,

```
> dt
   Z HDATA Bin_names
1: 1  1234         0
2: 2  5678         0
3: 3  9ACB         0
4: 4  DEF0         1
>
```

How do I get this to give me an output that looks like this,

```
   Z HDATA C15 C14 C13 C12 C11 C10 C9 C8 C7 C6 C5 C4 C3 C2 C1 C0
1: 1  1234   0   0   0   1   0   0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  0
2: 2  5678   0   1   0   1   0   0  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
3: 3  9ABC   1   0   0   1   1   0  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0
4: 4  DEF0   1   1   0   1   1   1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
```

My actual data table has about 10M rows so I am looking for a fast method to do this.
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it seems one of the problems is that `hex2bin` doesn't seem to vectorize properly. It returns one vector with 16 values for each input. Really we would like to split each number separately. And it also seems the `data.table` `:=` operator likes to have a list on the right hand of the assignment rather than a matrix from what I can tell. So let us define a helper function

```
bincols<-function(x) {
   y <- t(Vectorize(hex2bin)(as.character(x)))
   c(unname(as.data.table(y)))
}
```

This will create a list with 16 elements where each element is a vector of 0/1 for each value that's passed to the function. Then we can use this with your assignment command

```
dt[, c(Bin_names) := bincols(HDATA)]
```

So this seems to work. I have a feeling some of the transformations i'm doing might be unnecessary, so maybe someone with more `data.table` experience might suggest some improvements.

Comment: You can just wrap `Bin_names` like `c(Bin_names)` as well.

Comment: `dt[,c(Bin_names):=data.table(t(sapply(as.character(dt$HDATA),hex2bin)))]` would be a minor simplification avoiding the need for `Vectorize` in the helper function.

Comment: Well, that basically is what `Vectorize` does; i think it's more readable with `Vectorize`.